# Umlauts get lost on another system after encoding and decoding Base64

Tags: java, base64, zip

Giving the following implementation I face the problem that, on another system, the XML file is missing the Umlaute (ä, ü, ö) compared to the origin XML file. Instead of the Umlaute the replacement character is inserted in the XML file. (*0xEF 0xBF 0xBD (efbfbd)*)

- Get a zip file containing a XML with Umlauts
- Decompress the zip file
- Encode the xml content to a Base64 payload and save it to the db
- Querys the entity
- Get the Base64 payload
- Decode the Base64 content
- Decoded Base64 content is a XML which should contain the origin Umlauts

Whats driving me crazy is the fact that the decoded Base64 content is missing the Umlaute on another system. Instead of the umlaute I get the replacement character. On my system the same implementation is working without the replacement.

The following code is just a MCVE to explain the problem which works fine on my system but on a other system (Windows Server 2013) misses the umlaute after decode.

```
String requestUrl = "https://myserver/mypath/Message_166741.zip";    
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(String requestUrl = "https://myserver/mypath/Message_166741.zip";);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
    byte[] decompressedInputStream = decompress(inputStream);

    String content = null;
    content = new String(decompressedInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String originFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'_origin.xml'").format(new Date());
    String originFileNameWithPath = String.format("C:\\temp\\Tests\\%1$s", originFileName);

    // File contains the expected umlauts
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(originFileNameWithPath), content);

    String payloadUTF8 = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(content.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    String payload = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(content.getBytes()));
    String payloadJavaBase64 = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(ZipUtils.compress(content.getBytes())));

    String xmlMessageJavaBase64;
    byte[] compressedBinaryJavaBase64 = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(payloadJavaBase64);
    byte[] decompressedBinaryJavaBase64= ZipUtils.decompress(compressedBinaryJavaBase64);
    xmlMessageJavaBase64 = new String(decompressedBinaryJavaBase64, "UTF-8");

    String xmlMessageUTF8;
    byte[] compressedBinaryUTF8 = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(payloadUTF8);
    byte[] decompressedBinaryUTF8 = ZipUtils.decompress(compressedBinaryUTF8);
    xmlMessageUTF8 = new String(decompressedBinaryUTF8, "UTF-8");

    String xmlMessage;
    byte[] compressedBinary = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload);
    byte[] decompressedBinary = ZipUtils.decompress(compressedBinary);
    xmlMessage = new String(decompressedBinary, "UTF-8");

    String processedFileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'_processed.xml'").format(new Date());
    String processedFileNameUTF8 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'_processedUTF8.xml'").format(new Date());
    String processedFileNameJavaBase64 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'_processedJavaBase64.xml'").format(new Date());


    // These files do not contain the umlauts anymore.
    // Instead of the umlauts a replacement character is inserted (0xEF 0xBF 0xBD (efbfbd))
    String processedFileNameWithPath = String.format("C:\\temp\\Tests\\%1$s", processedFileName);
    String processedFileNameWithPathUTF8 = String.format("C:\\temp\\Tests\\%1$s", processedFileNameUTF8);
    String processedFileNameWithPathJavaBase64 = String.format("C:\\temp\\Tests\\%1$s", processedFileNameJavaBase64);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(processedFileNameWithPath), xmlMessage);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(processedFileNameWithPathUTF8), xmlMessageUTF8);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(processedFileNameWithPathJavaBase64), xmlMessageJavaBase64);
```

The three files are just for testing purpose but I hope you getting the problem

**Edit**

Both ways create XML file with ü, ö, ä **on my machine**
Only the WITHOUT implementation create an XML XML file with ü, ö, ä **on another system** The "content" string of WITH UTF-8 contains for ü  =>

```
// WITHOUT UTF-8 IN BYTE[] => STRING CTOR
byte[] dci = decompress(inputStream);
content = new String(dci);

byte[] compressedBinary = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);
byte[] decompressedBinary = ZipUtils.decompress(compressedBinary);
String xml = new String(decompressedBinary);


// WITH UTF-8 IN BYTE[] => STRING CTOR
byte[] dci = decompress(inputStream);    
content = String(dci, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);;

byte[] compressedBinary = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);
byte[] decompressedBinary = ZipUtils.decompress(compressedBinary);
String xml = new String(decompressedBinary, "UTF-8");
```

**Edit #2**

There also seems to be a difference between running the code in IntelliJ and outside of IntelliJ on my machine. Did not know that this makes such a huge difference. So - if I run the code outside of IntelliJ (*java.exe -jar myjarfile*)  the WITH UTF8 Part replaces the Ü. with ... I don't know. Notepad++ shows xFC. Funny: My raspberry pi shows both files with Ü where my Windows / notepad++ shows xFC.

That whole thing confuses me and I would like to understand whats the problem is. Also because the XML file contains the UTF8 as encode in header.

**Edit #3 Final Solution**

```
// ## SERVER
// Get ZIP from request URL
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(requestUrl);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

byte[] decompressedInputStream = decompress(inputStream);

// Produces a XML string which SHOULD contain ü, ö, ä
String xmlOfZipFileContent = new String(decompressedInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Just for testing write to file
String xmlOfZipFileSavePath = String.format("C:\\temp\\Tests\\%1$s", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'_original.xml'").format(new Date()));
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(xmlOfZipFileSavePath), xmlOfZipFileContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// The payloadExplicitUtf8 gets stored into the DB
String payload = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ZipUtils.compress(xmlOfZipFileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

// Store payload to db
// Client queries database and gets the payload
// payload = dbEntity.get().payload


// The following three lines is on client
byte[] compressedBinaryPayload = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(payload);
byte[] decompressedBinaryPayload = ZipUtils.decompress(compressedBinaryPayload);
String xmlMessageOutOfPayload = new String(decompressedBinaryPayload, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String xmlOfPayloadSavePath = String.format("C:\\temp\\Tests\\%1$s", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'_payload.xml'").format(new Date()));
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(xmlOfPayloadSavePath), xmlMessageOutOfPayload, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: What do you use to view the files? Some kind of binary/hex-editor? Note that the 3 files at the end of your code are written using platform default encoding which might not support umlauts.

Comment: The other system has a different default platform encoding than your system. That's why it works on yours but not there. The whole Base64 thing is not even related to anything here, it's just a basic encoding problem. But I'm happy to see all those `UTF-8` params specified in the `String` constructors! Usually with these kinds of questions the asker has no understanding (or the wrong understanding in the worst case) of character encoding.

Comment: So the code in question reproduces the problem? If I followed the logic correctly, the `xmlMessageUTF8` should contain the uncorrupted data. Can you verify if it contains the umlauts before writing to file? (I almost feel like clicking favorite on this question, it's so well presented).

Comment: @piet.t : I've tried notepad, notepad++, textpad, sublime and so on. But always the same problem. Further the viewer is not the point. I think that in the real implementation the problem is the encoding as the created payload, which gets stored into the db, already misses the Umlaute. Because if I copy the payload to **my local system** and decode it i also miss the umlaute.

Comment: @Kayaman The output files do not contain the umlauts. `yyyyMMddHHmm'_origin.xml`contains the umlaute. And after that they get missing. I assume that the umlaute loss happens within the `String payloadXX = ` lines. 
In the 'real code' the result of ` String payloadUTF8 = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(content.getBytes("UTF-8")));` gets stored into the db. Getting the payload out of the db and performing the decoding to XML also replaces the Umlauts on **my system**. I hope it is somehow clear.

Comment: Based on the above code I don't see how it could happen there, but if it's broken at that point, it's `content = new String(decompressedInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` that's your culprit. If the data sender uses platform default encoding and it's not `UTF8`, it will be corrupted there.

Comment: @Kayaman Ok, but I explicitly say UTF_8 so I assume that the default encoding is ignored? Further, `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(originFileNameWithPath), content);` which uses the line you mentioned to produce the content creates an XML file containing all umlauts.

Comment: You specify `UTF8` on the **receiving** side. If the sending side doesn't specify the encoding explicitly, it's broken code. Otherwise the above code looks fine for the `payloadUTF8` version (the others are at least technically broken since they use `getBytes()` without the encoding).

Comment: You are using the platform default encoding in various places: `payload` and `payloadJavaBase64` are Base64-encodings of the data in platform default encoding. Also every occurence of `FileUtils.writeStringToFile`uses the default encoding to write the file.

Comment: @piet.t it's true that the default encoding is used to write to the file, which is bad if the XML specifies that it's in `UTF-8`, but the resulting file isn't actually `UTF8`. However: it wouldn't result in the umlauts disappearing, as pretty much all normal encodings do support umlauts. The replacement character appearing means that `non-UTF8` bytes are being decoded as `UTF8`, replacing the non-decodable bytes with the replacement character. The `payload` and `payloadJavaBase64` are wrong though (as I also indicated in my comment).

Comment: @Kayaman : What do you excatly mean with **receiving** side? The receiving side is in _real_ implementation a scheduled job downloading the zip file. I've checked the code again, so the problem shoudd be following line? `dbEntity.Payload = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(artifact.payload.bytes));` ? Thats the point **before** the entity gets stored to the DB and after the ZIP is decompressed by `content = new String(decompress(entity.getContent()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. As far as I can see the charset is not provided when assigning the encoded value to the property?

Comment: If `artifact.payload` is a string, then yes, getting the bytes would mean any data is converted to the platform default encoding at that point, which would of course be wrong.

Comment: Yes, its a string. But I made a mistake. I mixed some things up. The line `content = new String(decompressedInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` on the other system already replaces the umlauts. So my `yyyyMMddHHmm'_origin.xml` **does not contain** the umlauts whereas the xml in the zip does. But why does that not happen on my system? That's what Im missing to understand.

Comment: Are you saying that **one** server provides the `decompressedInputStream` (or the stream where it originates from), and **two** clients get different results (using the same server data)?

Comment: **Server A**: Provides a GET http API to get a ZIP file using a URI with two parameters. For example `https://servera.com:123/x/theServlet?Param1=0&Param2=166741`. The result is the ZIP file to download.
**Server B**: Calls the API with the uri. Takes the result and does `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();` 
`content = new String(decompress(entity.getContent()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` Then the content gets into db after `dbEntity.Payload = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(artifact.payload.bytes))`. Artifact just holds values. artifact.payload = content

Comment: Uh... first you have `content`, then you have `artifact.payload.bytes`?

Comment: Seems like `content = new String(decompressedInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` is the problem. When I remove the second parameter the origin file contains the umlaute on the other system. But then only this line call `String payloadUTF8 = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(content.getBytes("UTF-8")));` seems to get the correct output in the file. the other miss the umlaute. Damn.. why.

Comment: The server isn't sending `UTF8` data. You're expecting `UTF8` as the end result though, that's why "receive non-UTF8" -> "write UTF8" gives you the correct result. You need to know the encoding of the data the server sends and use that to parse the data from the server instead of `UTF8` like you had.

Comment: @Kayaman :  the implementation is a little bit confusing to be honest. artifact.payload.bytes. `Artifact artifact = new Artifact()`. `artifact.payload = content`. then payload get transformed: `artifact.payload = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(artifact.payload.bytes))` where bytes == getBytes(). Don't know why its working without the get. Its grails / groovy / java implementation

Comment: @Kayaman but why does this work on my local system using the same file but not on the other system / Server b? That makes no sense to me as they are processing the same zip file. Further, the downloaded XML contains the encoding=UTF8 in the header

Comment: Are you saying they both process the same `decompressedInputStream`? Because that's the problem point here, and you can't have different results for the same `decompressedInputStream` when doing `new String(decompressedInputStream, "UTF-8");`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your situation seems to be the following:

```
// Decompress data from the server, it's in ISO-8859-1 or similar 1 byte encoding
byte[] dci = decompress(inputStream);

// Data gets corrupted because of wrong charset
// This is where ü gets converted to unicode replacement character
content = new String(dci, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The rest of the code uses UTF8 explicitly, but it doesn't matter as the data has already been corrupted at this point. In the end you expect an `UTF-8` encoded file.

---

> Also because the XML file contains the UTF8 as encode in header.

That doesn't prove anything. If you treat it as just a text file, you can write it out in as many encodings as you want to, and it would still claim to be UTF8.

Comment: I should start some kind of remote charset problem debugging service, because it's incredibly hard to convey the necessary information through text, but really easy for me to actually find and solve the problem.

Comment: I've added the first post. Should be easier

Comment: What you're describing shouldn't be possible. If in all cases the `byte[] dci` contains the same bytes, the only possible difference could be in the WITHOUT case.

Comment: Had a mistake in the without. Removed the UTF_8 charset at new String. So - running on  server / another machine: The WITHOUT UTF_8 part runs fine. The WITH UTF_8 part produces the character replacement in XML file. BUT both ways work fine on my local machine... **assuming** I run the code in IntelliJ. Outside of IntelliJ I get the same result as on the server... wow. Thats damn confusing. Further: Why is setting StandardCharsets.UTF_8 bad or does not work? Because the XML file is, based on the header, encoding=UTF_8. MAkes no sense

Comment: If you get the same (correct) result for both WITH & WITHOUT, it means the platform default encoding (which may be different inside IntelliJ) is `UTF-8`, and the data is `UTF-8`. If you get a different (incorrect) result for WITHOUT, it means the platform encoding is not `UTF-8`. However unicode replacement characters appear when non-UTF8 data is parsed as UTF8, so I'm having a hard time believing your data really is UTF8. Also it's perfectly possible to write a file in non-UTF8 that says "this file is in UTF8", so the XML can lie to you.

Comment: @Kayman Without StandardCharsets.UTF_8 on String initialising everything works fine outside IntelliJ. So I assume that the line `content = String(dci, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` is the root problem for replacing Ü by something else. As I get the data from an external provider (the zip file with the XML) is there a way to verify the encoding of the file?

Comment: You could open it with a hex editor and see if `Ü` is encoded in 2 bytes (UTF8) or one (probably ISO-8859-1).

Comment: Then you've got UTF-8, baby. Now treat it everywhere as UTF-8.

Comment: @Kayman posted my final solution which works on my client and also on my server system. The failure point for me was the fact that running the code within and outside of IntelliJ produces other results. That was really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
byte[] decompressedInputStream = decompress(inputStream);
```

Fine, and it is *assumed* that the bytes are in UTF-8, as:

```
String content = new String(decompressedInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Should the bytes not be in UTF-8, you could try Windows Latin-1:

```
Charset.forName("Windows-1252")
```

Otherwise `decompressedInputStream` can be used whereever `content` is converted to bytes in UTF-8.

```
...
```

The `FileUtils.writeStringToFile` without encoding specified uses the default platform encoding.

```
// File contains the expected umlauts
//FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(originFileNameWithPath), content);
```

Better is to ensure that UTF-8 is written. Either add the encoding to convert the Unicode String to bytes in UTF-8, or simply write the original bytes:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(originFileNameWithPath), decompressedInputStream);
```

Also the Base64 encoded ***UTF-8*** bytes of the String should be used:

```
String payloadUTF8 = Base64.encodeBase64String(ZipUtils.compress(
    content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

String payloadJavaBase64 = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(
    ipUtils.compress(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
```

The standard JavaSE Base64 will do; though do not use its decodeString and encodeString as that uses ISO-8859-1, Latin-1.